# My selectbox becomes disabled when accessed through session

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel framework and some jquery code.

The problem is that, when i submit the data, it is successfully saved in session. when i get back to previous page, My select box shows the selected value  but select-box is disabled. i am totally confused. what shall i do here?

Here is my HTML code:-

```
<div class="one-row">
  <?php foreach ($services as $key => $allservices){ 
    if($key <= 3){  
      if(!empty($data['services'])){
        if(in_array($allservices['id'],$data['services'])) {
          $checked = "checked";
        } else {
          $checked = "";
        }
      } else {
        $checked = "";
      } 
    ?>
    <div class="div_img_part-2"> 
      <span class="img_part_class-2">
        <img src="{{ 
            asset('images/ServiceImages/'. $allservices['image'])}}"></span>
        <span class="text_part_class-2">
        <span class="check-box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="
          <?php echo $allservices['id']; ?>" <?= $checked; ?>><?php echo $allservices['name']; ?></span>
      </span>
      <select name="services[<?php echo $allservices['name'];?>]"class="selectpicker">
        <option value="">Select Your Sevice</option>
        <option value="Salon" <?php if(!empty($data['services'][$allservices['name']])){ if($data['services'][$allservices['name']] == "Salon") {?> selected
        <?php } } ?> >Salon</option>
        <option value="Mobile beautician" <?php if(!empty($data['services'][$allservices['name']])){ if($data['services'][$allservices['name']] == "Mobile beautician") {?> selected
        <?php } }?> >Mobile beautician</option>
        <option value="Both" <?php if(!empty($data['services'][$allservices['name']])){ if($data['services'][$allservices['name']] == "Both") {?> selected
        <?php } } ?>>Both</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

And my Jquery Code looks:-

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".div_img_part-2 .selectpicker").attr("disabled",true);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    $(".check-box input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function () {
      if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find(".selectpicker").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
      }else{
      $(this).parents(".div_img_part-2").find(".selectpicker").attr("disabled",true);
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

Firstly Select
[image]

After Select(Edit)
[image]

Note:- when user selects the checkbox, the selectbox will be active at first time of registration. All my data are saved in session in Laravel please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this once the page is loaded:

```
$(".check-box input[type='checkbox']").trigger("change");
```

So the checkbox values will be recognised by the page.

Comment: Works like charm :)